# Unity - multiplayer game using mirror

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1q4s.gif)I'm using mirror for **local server** between multiply gamePlayers.
I have a problem sync non players objects.
I want each Player to have a button to be able to rool two dices and that the player on host will be able to see what client do and apposite. I'm still confused , don't know when to use   [Command] and     [ClientRpc]
btw, I create my dices like that, and called this on the method **OnStartServer()**:

**GameObject newPrize = Instantiate(prizePrefab.gameObject, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
// add this game object to all clients
NetworkServer.Spawn(newPrize);**

Thank you so much!

Comment: I alert you that it is a really bad idea to try using "Mirror".  Just use the ordinary, new, multiplayer networking now available in Unity for some years.

Comment: UNET? It is soon deperacted

Comment: You're right, waiting for NetCode is a joke.   But Mirror just doesn't work.  UNET still works great.

Comment: @Fattie That's interesting! Mirror seems surrounded by fumes of success and technical faculty publicly. Is there any article etc. on Mirror's fatal flaws?

Comment: i would just google, there are SO MANY "comparison articles", due to the unity MP crisis.

Comment: Opinions based in "this is bad and you should Google it" are of no help at all. I have searched and I didn't find any article that prove Mirror is that bad, only one of the concurrent MLAPI, which says Mirror has less features than MLAPI and some limitations related to its history. However, it does not prove that Mirror has something to do related to OP misfortune (which possibly can find some answers in this page: https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Guides/GameObjects/SpawnObject.html but I can't confirm that).